# why does my delete search linked list function not working?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, c-strings, function-definition

i have this problem when im using this function, i want to delete all the node with the given string, but when i run this on my program it deletes all from the first find char ex[], im new to c please guide me

```
void delSearch(char ex[]){
    int del;
    struct file *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp->ex,ex)==0){
            file *temp2 = temp->next;
            file *temp3 = temp;
            temp->next=temp2;
            free(temp3);
            temp3 = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag C++ if your question is related to pure C code.

Comment: `temp->next=temp2;` is equivalent to `temp->next=temp->next;` which looks a bit redundant

Comment: @Ollie It is unclear whether you need to delete the first node with the given string or all nodes with the given string.

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous node. So that you can do something like `prev->next = temp->next;` to remove the `temp` node from the list. You are probably trying to do that with `temp->next=temp2;`. But that is wrong. It does nothing as it is just `temp->next=temp->next` (as already pointed out in the above comment).

Comment: @Ollie I asked you a question did not I?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i need to delete all the node with the given string

Comment: The most elegant answer involves a pointer to pointer. (in the current version you could not delete the first node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the local variable `del`

```
int del;
```

is not used within the function.

The function does not change the global pointer `head` provided that it points to a node that stores the given string.

Also you need to update the data member `next` of the node that precedes to the node to be deleted.

The function can look the following way as it is shown below.

```
void delSearch( const char ex[] )
{
    while ( head && strcmp( head->ex, ex ) == 0 )
    {
        struct file *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    if ( head )
    {
        for ( struct file *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( strcmp( current->next->ex, ex ) == 0 )
            {
                struct file *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to know how many nodes were deleted after calling the function then the function can be changed the following way.

```
size_t delSearch( const char ex[] )
{
    size_t total = 0;
    
    while ( head && strcmp( head->ex, ex ) == 0 )
    {
        struct file *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
        ++total;
    }
    
    if ( head )
    {
        for ( struct file *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( strcmp( current->next->ex, ex ) == 0 )
            {
                struct file *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
                ++total;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

An alternative function definition can look the following way

```
size_t delSearch( const char ex[] )
{
    size_t total = 0;
    
    for ( struct file **current = &head; *current != NULL; )
    {
        if ( strcmp( ( *current )->ex, ex ) == 0 )
        {
            struct file *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            free( tmp );
            ++total;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

Comment: wow, it really works thank you so much for your help sir i really appreciate it! now i know what im doing wrong

Comment: @Ollie Just mark the answer as the best answer.:)

Comment: sorry, how do i mark? im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Ollie You already marked the answer as the best answer.:)